# PHP Find Array Index Name

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have an array that looks like this when I perform a var_dump:

```
array(1) { [300000001]=> string(15) "Find Compatible" }
```

Instead of printing the value "Find Compatible", how can I use the index name 300000001 as a variable?

Comment: several options, do you just want the first key? the key when the values is known ? .. ?

Comment: If you want to use the key as a variable you have to assign it to something.

Comment: As a variable? That number won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first key:

```
$first_key = key($array);
```

search based on value:

```
$key=array_search('Find Compatible',$array);
```

Comment: Of course! Yeah, that works. How silly of me. I should've checked that there'd be a function for this. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the keys of a given `$array`, you can iterate using [foreach](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   echo $key;
}
```

Comment: How about some `array_keys()` instead?

Comment: If the programmer wants to create other array with the keys, he may  use `array_keys()`, why not?

Comment: There are various applications of `foreach`, but --- "If you want to get all the keys of a given $array" - then there is `array_keys()`

Comment: As I said before, *if* the programmer wants to allocate another array and store on it. If not, there is no need of such use.

Comment: I will just repeat the key phrase from the question "Find Array Index Name"

Comment: "Find Array Index Name (aka key)" not "Create Array with the keys"

Comment: exactly. OP wants to find a key. You're just retrieving all of them